# Event handler that isn't working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've created a date picker text box using JQueryUI (see the HTML code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmJdk) which uses an ASP.NET `TextBox`. I created the `onTextChanged` event handler like this:

```html
<asp:TextBox OnTextChanged="EventHandler" ID="datepicker" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Using Visual Studio 2012 I double clicked the element in design view to create the event handler in my .cs file and proceeded to place a JavaScript alert inside it to check that it works. The .cs event handler looks like this:

```
protected void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('ok');",
        true);
}
```

**Here's the problem:** When I use the date picker and the date changes I don't get my JavaScript alert. I assume this means there is something wrong with the event handler but I'm not sure what. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and to see if `EventHandler` is being called, on text changed ?

Comment: Double clicking on a design element creates the click event, not the ontextchanged event.  Could the wiring be screwed up in the .designer file?

Comment: Bit of a weird method name `EventHandler`? Are you sure this even compliles?

Comment: Yes the EventHandler never seems to get called on the text change

Comment: Setting AutoPostback to true should fix the issue but you still have to exit the control for the event to be hit. Btw, what are you trying to accomplish? The whole workflow seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @JFM It is basically a booking form and when the date is changed the available booking times in a DropDownList change to ones that are available (the JS alert is just there to test my other code will go in there instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `TextBox` to true.

E.g.

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="EventHandler" ID="datepicker" runat="server" />
```